# Access to the path 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers.dll' is denied

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

When im trying to add new NuGet Packages I get this error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers.dll' is denied.

Tried to restore but same error again.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: It could mean that file is in use

Answer (score 0):

In case any "access denied" error related to package installation these solutions might solve the issue:

1. of course make sure that your user account has access to your project/solutions folder.
2. Close visual studio Instance then delete the packages folder under your solution folder (don't worry it will be automatically created again).
3. run visual studio as Administrator and then reopen your project and run `update-package -reinstall` under Tools-->Nuget Package Manager--> Package Manager Console

Then, rebuild your project again.

if all these solution did not work, you can copy the project directory, deleted the files which had accessed denied error then rebuild the project and updated the older references.